# Approximating $\pi$ with the help of a regular $k$-sided polygon

Tags: power-series, circles, pi, polygons

I'm reading "An Introduction to Computational Physics" by Tao Pang. In it, he writes the following. In general, if the side length of a regular inscribed $k$-sided polygon is
denoted as $l_k$ and the corresponding diameter is taken to be the unit of length,
then the approximation of π is given by:

\begin{equation}
\pi_k=kl_k
\end{equation}

The exact value of $\pi$ is the limit of $\pi_k$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. The value of $\pi_k$ obtained from the calculations of the k-sided polygon can be formally written as
\begin{equation}
\pi_{k}=\pi_{\infty}+\frac{c_{1}}{k}+\frac{c_{2}}{k^{2}}+\frac{c_{3}}{k^{3}}+\cdots
\end{equation}
where $\pi_\infty = π$ and $c_i$ , for $i = 1, 2, . . . ,\infty,$ are the coefficients to be determined.

The last part is the one I don't understand. Why is this form of expansion allowed and how is this the formal way to do it? Is it because of the undetermined coefficients? To my mind, you can expand anything in a series like that if you include undetermined coefficients.

Comment: $\pi_k=k\sin (\pi /k)$. For any $x$ we have $\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}/((2n+1)!).$ If instead we inscribe the circle inside a regular $k$-gon, the perimeter of that $k$-gon is $\pi^*_k=k\tan (\pi /k).$ We have $\pi_k<\pi<\pi^*_k. $  Archimedes repeatedly used the half-angle formulas $|\cos (x/2)|=\sqrt {(1+\cos x)/2}$ and $|\sin (x/2)|= \sqrt {(1-\cos x)/2)}$ and with $k=96$ deduced $10/71<\pi -3<1/7.$

Comment: So it is a Taylor expansion but the coefficients are left undetermined because they include $\pi$ which we try to calculate in the first place? I also tried to determine the $c_1$ coefficient in my original question and it turns out to be small, maybe it's because this term should vanish in the expansion of $sin(x)$.

Comment: The co-efficients are not "undetermined" ; they have exact values. But they do "include" $\pi$.  For $some$ values of $k$ we can get a closed-form expression (or a diiferent infinite series) for $\pi_k$ that does not mention $\pi.$ E.g. $k\in\{6,12,24,48,96\}.$ And $c_1=0.$

Comment: Well, then I still don't understand how the expansion in my original post came to be.

Comment: From the power series for $\sin (\pi /k)$ we have $\pi -\pi_k=\pi x^2/3!-\pi x^4/5!+....$ where $x=\pi /k.$

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is why we can expand $\pi_k$ in a series with undetermined coefficients.